# Showing that $g : U \to \mathcal{L}(\Bbb R^n; \Bbb R^n)$ given by $g(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}f^k(x)$ is $C^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

The problem is the following:

> Let $f:U\to \mathcal{L} (\Bbb R^n;\Bbb R^n)$ such that $f\in C^\infty$ on the open set $U\subset \Bbb R^m$. For $k\in \Bbb N$ and $x\in U$, define $$f^k(x)=f(x)f(x)\cdots f(x)~~~~~~~~~\text{(k-factors)}$$ and show that $g:U\to \mathcal{L}(\Bbb R^n; \Bbb R^n)$, given by $g(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}f^k(x)$, is $C^\infty$.

I found that the derivative $Df^k(x):\Bbb R^m\to \mathcal{L} (\Bbb R^n;\Bbb R^n)$ of $f^k(x)$ is given by $$Df^k(x)(h)=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1} f^n(x) Df(x)(h) f^{k-n-1}(x).$$

Now I aim to prove that $g\in C^\infty$. Any hints?

Comment: If $f^k(x)$ just means $f(x)^k$, then $$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{f(x)^k}{k!} = e^{f(x)}-1 $$ by the series definition of the exponential function.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio But what does $e^{f(x)}$ even mean when $f$ is a linear operator? The only sensible definition is that same series definition, which makes it no easier than the original problem. That said, looking at matrix exponentials may point the OP in the right direction.

Comment: @ChristianSykes: if $M$ is a square matrix, $e^{M}$ is defined as $\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{M^k}{k!}$. If we are allowed to exponentiate matrices, we are also allowed to exponentiate linear operators.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Agreed, but that doesn't assist in showing smoothness. You can't just differentiate naively.

Comment: @ChristianSykes: I do not agree. It is simple to estimate the size of $e^{M+\varepsilon I}- e^M$ by the series definition.

Comment: How about prove that $A\mapsto e^A$ is smooth in $L(\mathbb{R}^N,\mathbb{R}^N)$ to $L(\mathbb{R}^N,\mathbb{R}^N)$  and then we use the chain rule to conclusion !

Comment: $f$ has a different domain and codomain, it doesn't make sense to compose $f$ with itself.

Comment: @T.Gunn You are clearly right. My mistake. (This pertained to an edit I proposed.)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, this is true. The problem above is from a textbook that I am studying. This problem is 6.1,  and the aim of problem 6.3 is to prove that the application $X\mapsto e^X$ is $C^\infty$ and its derivative in $X=0$ is the identity linear transformation. Here, by definition, $e^X=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{X^n}{n!}$, where $X\in \Bbb R^{m^2}$. So I think we have to use 6.1 (the main problem of the post) to prove 6.3 (the problem I described here).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio with that I mean you can't use smoothness of $e^{f(x)}$, since demonstrate this will be an application of the problem of this question.